# Can we install both nginx and lamp in ubuntu?

Tags: nginx, lamp

In NGINX it's difficult to configure for each project, but I need it for one of my project. 
In lamp its easy to install any project.
So, I want to install both NGINX and LAMP on same system.
Can, I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

Nginx has multiple uses and one of them is ability to serve websites, the same way as Apache2 does, just with different configuration.

LAMP stands for:

Linux

Apache

MySQL

PHP/Python/Perl

By including an Nginx, you don't replace whole LAMP stack, just one component.

In your situation you want to replace Apache2 web server with Nginx, so your new stack is named LEMP by convention. It won't have an effect on any existing applications if configured correctly.

Nginx and Apache2 are just programs running as background applications and they don't exclude each other either.

Installation instructions can be found on Digital Ocean tutorials page:
[How To Install Linux, Nginx, MySQL, PHP (LEMP stack) in Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-in-ubuntu-16-04)